# Task Workflow Rules Not Firing

Tags: workflow

I have a workflow rule on opportunity that creates a task. I also have a workflow rule that does a field update on tasks. When I manually create a task that matches the task WFR criteria, the field update fires. When the task is created by the opportunity WFR, the task field update doesn't happen.

Is it true that creation of tasks through a WFR means task WFR don't execute?

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with checking the re-evaluate workflows checkbox ?

Comment: That is only an option on Field Updates. When I create a task in a workflow, that option isn't there.

Comment: Searched and tried the same , I think it is not possible and using a trigger is the only option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Workflow rules on tasks do not fire when the task is created by a different workflow rule. If you want to do field updates or other actions, you need to write a trigger to perform those actions.